# How can i show images in webkit?

Tags: swift, image, macos, google-chrome, webkit

### Current status

- I have developed a simple Mac OS application.
- This application searches recipes by WebKit.

  ```
  import Cocoa
  import WebKit

  class ViewController: NSViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: NSTextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var browserWebView: WKWebView!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      browserWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
      searchTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
      let StringURL:String = "https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ピザ+inurl:/recipe/+site:cookpad.com"
      let url = URL(string:StringURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)
      let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
      self.browserWebView.load(urlRequest)

  }
  override var representedObject: Any? {
      didSet {
      }
  }
  }
  ```

### Problem

- GoogleChrome shows food images, but WebKit doesn’t (see images below).

  - GoogleChrome

  [image: GoogleChrome]

  - WebKit(Xcode Simulatror)

  [image: WebKit(Xcode Simulatror)]
- I want to read enough texts also images, so I choose not "image tab" but "all tab" option

### Question

- How can i show images by webkit?

### Development Environment

- Swift3

### Tried → Error

- Tried : Google Chrome view with JavaScript disabled is the same result as WebKit (Xcode Simulator). So I added the following code.

  ```
  let preferences = WKPreferences()
  preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

  let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
  configuration.preferences = preferences
  ```

  →Error : Default WebKit enables JavaScript, so this approach doesn’t resolve the problem.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added customUserAgent in viewDidLoad() to solve this problem.

```
browserWebView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36”
```

- WebKit(Xcode Simulatror)

[image: CookingLog_customUserAgent]